# ReactJS switching input element from controlled to uncontrolled with defined value state

Tags: reactjs, forms, input

Part of my code which fails looks like:

```
const normalizeInput = (value, previousValue) => {
    if (!value) return value;
    const currentValue = value.replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
    const cvLength = currentValue.length;

    if (!previousValue || value.length > previousValue.length) {
    if (cvLength < 4) return currentValue;
    if (cvLength < 7) return `(${currentValue.slice(0, 3)}) ${currentValue.slice(3)}`;
    return `(${currentValue.slice(0, 3)}) ${currentValue.slice(3, 6)}-${currentValue.slice(6, 10)}`;
    }
    else {
       if (cvLength < 4) return currentValue;
       if (cvLength < 7) return `(${currentValue.slice(0, 3)}) ${currentValue.slice(3)}`;
    }
};


class Example extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    console.log(JSON.stringify(props))

    this.state = {
        editable: {},
        phoneNumber: '(123) 555-1234'
    }
}

handlePhoneChange(id, value) {
    this.setState(prevState=> ({ [id]: normalizeInput(value, prevState[id]) }));
};

render(){
    return(

        <input
        type="text"
        className="form-control react-form-input"
        id="phoneNumber"
        name="phoneNumber"
        value={this.state.phoneNumber}
        onChange={(e) => {this.handlePhoneChange('phoneNumber', e.target.value)}}
        />

    )}
}
```

It will complain as

> A component is changing a controlled input of type text to be
>   uncontrolled. Input elements should not switch from controlled to
>   uncontrolled

on `value={this.state.phoneNumber}`

but when I will set it as `value={this.state.phoneNumber || ''}` will not but then on change will remove whole `phoneNumber` value instead on character.

Any tips on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because your `normalizeInput` does not return anything when `value.length <= previousValue.length` (*when you delete something*)

So the `undefined` gets stored in your state and later given as `value` to your `input`, in effect making it uncontrolled.

---

The `|| ''` fixes that because when your value is `undefined` you pass the `''` empty string and so the `input` never receives an `undefined` value.

Comment: OK, but what causing to delete whole input value when I will add `|| '` and then I will delete something? Should be better to have added `else` statement in `normalizeInput` to return edited value?

Comment: I have added `else` statement to the `normalizeInput` and it still complains about switching element to uncontrolled.

Comment: @JackTheKnife if `cvLength >= 7` in your `else` block, you still return `undefined`. There should be no way your `normalizeInput` to return `undefined` or the `input` will become uncontrolled.